When navigating away from the page, file upload is not saved in the browser
Okay so I'm having this issue when uploading files. Once a input file upload is done, if I navigate away from the page in the same window then go back to the page using the back button, the uploaded file isn't saved and is reset. Likewise, if I were to do the same with inputs with a type of text, it will save the input value. What is this behaviour and how can I save the file upload without using localstorage or session storage. Here's the codepen for reference:
https://codepen.io/OptimalLearner/pen/QWMGyZj
<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Material+Icons|Material+Icons+Outlined" rel="stylesheet">
<form class="form-container" enctype='multipart/form-data'>
    <div class="upload-files-container">
        <div class="drag-file-area">
            <span class="material-icons-outlined upload-icon"> file_upload </span>
            <h3 class="dynamic-message"> Drag & drop any file here </h3>
            <label class="label"> or <span class="browse-files"> <input type="file" class="default-file-input"/> <span class="browse-files-text">browse file</span> <span>from device</span> </span> </label>
        </div>
        <span class="cannot-upload-message"> <span class="material-icons-outlined">error</span> Please select a file first <span class="material-icons-outlined cancel-alert-button">cancel</span> </span>
        <div class="file-block">
            <div class="file-info"> <span class="material-icons-outlined file-icon">description</span> <span class="file-name"> </span> | <span class="file-size">  </span> </div>
            <span class="material-icons remove-file-icon">delete</span>
            <div class="progress-bar"> </div>
        </div>
        <button type="button" class="upload-button"> Upload </button>
    </div>
</form>

var isAdvancedUpload = function() {
  var div = document.createElement('div');
  return (('draggable' in div) || ('ondragstart' in div && 'ondrop' in div)) && 'FormData' in window && 'FileReader' in window;
}();

let draggableFileArea = document.querySelector(".drag-file-area");
let browseFileText = document.querySelector(".browse-files");
let uploadIcon = document.querySelector(".upload-icon");
let dragDropText = document.querySelector(".dynamic-message");
let fileInput = document.querySelector(".default-file-input");
let cannotUploadMessage = document.querySelector(".cannot-upload-message");
let cancelAlertButton = document.querySelector(".cancel-alert-button");
let uploadedFile = document.querySelector(".file-block");
let fileName = document.querySelector(".file-name");
let fileSize = document.querySelector(".file-size");
let progressBar = document.querySelector(".progress-bar");
let removeFileButton = document.querySelector(".remove-file-icon");
let uploadButton = document.querySelector(".upload-button");
let fileFlag = 0;

fileInput.addEventListener("click", () => {
    fileInput.value = '';
    console.log(fileInput.value);
});

fileInput.addEventListener("change", e => {
    console.log(" > " + fileInput.value)
    uploadIcon.innerHTML = 'check_circle';
    dragDropText.innerHTML = 'File Dropped Successfully!';
    document.querySelector(".label").innerHTML = `drag & drop or <span class="browse-files"> <input type="file" class="default-file-input" style=""/> <span class="browse-files-text" style="top: 0;"> browse file</span></span>`;
    uploadButton.innerHTML = `Upload`;
    fileName.innerHTML = fileInput.files[0].name;
    fileSize.innerHTML = (fileInput.files[0].size/1024).toFixed(1) + " KB";
    uploadedFile.style.cssText = "display: flex;";
    progressBar.style.width = 0;
    fileFlag = 0;
});

uploadButton.addEventListener("click", () => {
    let isFileUploaded = fileInput.value;
    if(isFileUploaded != '') {
        if (fileFlag == 0) {
            fileFlag = 1;
            var width = 0;
            var id = setInterval(frame, 50);
            function frame() {
                if (width >= 390) {
                    clearInterval(id);
                    uploadButton.innerHTML = `<span class="material-icons-outlined upload-button-icon"> check_circle </span> Uploaded`;
                } else {
                    width += 5;
                    progressBar.style.width = width + "px";
                }
            }
        }
    } else {
        cannotUploadMessage.style.cssText = "display: flex; animation: fadeIn linear 1.5s;";
    }
});

cancelAlertButton.addEventListener("click", () => {
    cannotUploadMessage.style.cssText = "display: none;";
});

if(isAdvancedUpload) {
    ["drag", "dragstart", "dragend", "dragover", "dragenter", "dragleave", "drop"].forEach( evt => 
        draggableFileArea.addEventListener(evt, e => {
            e.preventDefault();
            e.stopPropagation();
        })
    );

    ["dragover", "dragenter"].forEach( evt => {
        draggableFileArea.addEventListener(evt, e => {
            e.preventDefault();
            e.stopPropagation();
            uploadIcon.innerHTML = 'file_download';
            dragDropText.innerHTML = 'Drop your file here!';
        });
    });

    draggableFileArea.addEventListener("drop", e => {
        uploadIcon.innerHTML = 'check_circle';
        dragDropText.innerHTML = 'File Dropped Successfully!';
        document.querySelector(".label").innerHTML = `drag & drop or <span class="browse-files"> <input type="file" class="default-file-input" style=""/> <span class="browse-files-text" style="top: -23px; left: -20px;"> browse file</span> </span>`;
        uploadButton.innerHTML = `Upload`;
        
        let files = e.dataTransfer.files;
        fileInput.files = files;
        console.log(files[0].name + " " + files[0].size);
        console.log(document.querySelector(".default-file-input").value);
        fileName.innerHTML = files[0].name;
        fileSize.innerHTML = (files[0].size/1024).toFixed(1) + " KB";
        uploadedFile.style.cssText = "display: flex;";
        progressBar.style.width = 0;
        fileFlag = 0;
    });
}

removeFileButton.addEventListener("click", () => {
    uploadedFile.style.cssText = "display: none;";
    fileInput.value = '';
    uploadIcon.innerHTML = 'file_upload';
    dragDropText.innerHTML = 'Drag & drop any file here';
    document.querySelector(".label").innerHTML = `or <span class="browse-files"> <input type="file" class="default-file-input"/> <span class="browse-files-text">browse file</span> <span>from device</span> </span>`;
    uploadButton.innerHTML = `Upload`;
});

